# Is there a way to specify the method at runtime in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of methods that I want to call named Method1, Method2, and so on. Is there a way I can just type in that number and then call the equivalent method? Delegates is one thing that comes to mind. Would this work?

Comment: If you have that many methods with similar semantics, then you probably need to work on fixing that instead of trying to come up with general solution to calling them.

Comment: It is more a directory thing. Makes it more modular. If I want to add another one, I just add it and add it to the directory and I'm done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
MyClass myObj = ...;
var method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("Method"+num);
var res = method.Invoke(myObj, new object[] {arg1, arg2});
```

You could also use a dictionary of delegates:

```
var byNumber = new Dictionary<int,Func<MyClass,int>> {
    {1, (c) => c.Method1()}
,   {2, (c) => c.Method2()}
,   {3, (c) => c.Method3()}
};

var res = byNumber[1](myObj);
```